# NVidia Quadro P2000's driver stopped working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I was using using the laptop this afternoon, discovered Netflix no longer worked all of a sudden so closed it and switched to another computer. When i opened it again, i couldn't get back into Ubuntu. Decided to switch back to the onboard Intel drivers temporarily to figure out what was going on:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Tried switching from Gnome to KDE and it made no difference, as soon as i select the nvidia driver again, it freezes upon login on Gnome and no login screen at all when on KDE until switching back to the Intel driver again. (switched from gdm to ssdm  in case that made a difference, no luck there)

Looking at the drivers, there are two NVidia drivers and a Nouveau driver, i've tried all three of them followed by a restart each time, each of them does exactly the same - system freezes after login in the case of Gnome or doesn't even get to the login screen on KDE.

[image]

Next, i tried adding some stuff to grub:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

added `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` and ran `sudo update-grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mem_sleep_default=deep nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

Followed by a restart, made no difference.

Not sure what other information i need to provide, so here's an `lspci` dump:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a340 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a338 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33c (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15db (rev 02)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
```

I also noticed there's a `core` file in my home directory

```
-rw------- 1 leuser leuser 698M Jul 31 23:42 core
```

This is the stock Ubuntu 18.04 that came with this Dell Precision 5530, had it for about 2 weeks now. Not sure if one of those automated patches could have caused this, that being said, had i run `apt upgrade`, the same would probably have happened.

Any idea what else i could try to get the Quadro P2000 working again? This Intel card is ok for basic things, but not much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works 100% in Ubuntu 19.04

So upgrading fixed it